align image at the top right corner
I would like to align image at the top right corner. The align right works fine, how can I align it vertically to the top?
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw,red,anchor=north west,align=right, inner sep=0,outer sep=0,text width=400pt,minimum height=200pt] {
        \includegraphics[width=50pt]{example-image-a} 
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Output:


Very unusual way to use a node. Normally one does not want to have the node significantly bigger than the content. I do not know what your end goal is!? As it is, it would be more clearly coded as a drawn rectangle and then an image node placed in the corner.

The usecase is try to put a  background image on beamer slide to right corner. if image not the full page size, then not able to move it to top right, so I try to draw a full page rectangle then move the logo to top right. yes, we can do it with two node, one node maybe a little bit tricky.

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, red, align=right, inner sep=0pt, text width=400pt, text depth=200pt] {\includegraphics[width=50pt]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Edit: Same output in a less obscure way:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red] (-400pt,-250pt) rectangle (0,0);
\node[inner sep=0pt, anchor=north east] {\includegraphics[width=50pt]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

